# Vue add variable to image src

Tags: javascript, vue.js

this might be a stupid question but i cant figure out how to put in a variable into an image url in Vue.
this is the code:

```
app.component("summoner-details", {
  template: `
    <div>
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    <img height='100' width='100' src="{{summonericon}}" alt='icon'/>
    <p>{{level}}</p>
    <p>{{summonericon}}</p>
    </div>
    `,
  props: ["name", "level", "summonericon"],
}),
  app.mount("#app");
```

The `{{}}` and `${}` method doesnt work. Anyone know how i would go about doing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vuejs variable in html attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289941/vuejs-variable-in-html-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) directive.

```js
<img height='100' width='100' v-bind:src="summonericon" alt='icon'/>
```

Comment: wow, that works was struggling with this for over an hour and its this simple, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<img height='100' width='100' :src="summonericon" alt='icon'/>
```

Maybe duplicate with [How can I use 'img src' in Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880956/how-can-i-use-img-src-in-vue-js)